# Starting application taking too long

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm working with eclipse, when starting an application, eclipse does the installation of the app on the device and then displays the message :
"Starting activity ----- on device -----" (which is my phone connected to the PC)
is taking a very long time and eventually nothing happens.
I've tried waiting even 10 minutes. Then I give up and open the app from my menu.

Did anyone encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see the logcat for error

Comment: Do not post your comment here.